# How to associated products to configurable product programmatically?

Tags: product, configurable-product

How can I associate simple products to a configurable product programmatically?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you know the product ids and the simple products have values for the configurable attribute:

```
$configurable_product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($id_of_configurable);
$configurable_product->getTypeInstance()
                     ->saveProducts(
                         $configurable_product, 
                         $array_of_simple_product_ids
                     );
```

Answer (score 0):

The below code create associated products pro-grammatically. The code create products with variable attributes.

```
 foreach ($simpleProductSkus as $simpleProdSku) {

        $i = 0;
        echo 'simple sku: '.$simpleProdSku . PHP_EOL;
        $simple_product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->loadByAttribute('sku', $simpleProdSku);
        if (is_object($simple_product)) {

            if ((int)$simple_product->getSize()) {
                $productsData = array( //['920'] = id of a simple product associated with this configurable
                    'label' => $simple_product->getAttributeText('size'), //attribute label
                    'attribute_id' => (int)$sizeAttributeId, //attribute ID of attribute 'color' in my store
                    'value_index' => (int)$simple_product->getSize(), //value of 'Green' index of the attribute 'color'
                    'is_percent' => '0', //fixed/percent price for this option
                    'pricing_value' => $simple_product->getPrice() //value for the pricing
                );
                $configurableProductsData[$simple_product->getId()] = $productsData;
                $configurableAttributesData[$i]['values'][] = $productsData;
                $i++;
            }
             if ((int)$simple_product->getColor()) {
                $productsData = array(
                    'label' => $simple_product->getAttributeText('color'),
                    'attribute_id' => (int)$colorAttributeId,
                    'value_index' => (int)$simple_product->getColor(),
                    'is_percent' => '0',
                    'pricing_value' => $simple_product->getPrice()
                );
                $configurableProductsData[$simple_product->getId()] = $productsData;
                $configurableAttributesData[$i]['values'][] = $productsData;
                $i++;
            }

             if ((int)$simple_product->getLength()) {
                $productsData = array( //['920'] = id of a simple product associated with this configurable
                    'label' => $simple_product->getAttributeText('length'), //attribute label
                    'attribute_id' => (int)$lengthAttributeId, //attribute ID of attribute 'color' in my store
                    'value_index' => (int)$simple_product->getLength(), //value of 'Green' index of the attribute 'color'
                    'is_percent' => '0',
                    'pricing_value' => $simple_product->getPrice() //value for the pricing
                );
                $configurableProductsData[$simple_product->getId()] = $productsData;
                $configurableAttributesData[$i]['values'][] = $productsData;
                $i++;
            }
            if ((int)$simple_product->getMaterial()) {
                $productsData = array(
                    'label' => $simple_product->getAttributeText('material'),
                    'attribute_id' => (int)$materialAttributeId,
                    'value_index' => (int)$simple_product->getMaterial(),
                    'is_percent' => '0',
                    'pricing_value' => $simple_product->getPrice()
                );
                $configurableProductsData[$simple_product->getId()] = $productsData;
                $configurableAttributesData[$i]['values'][] = $productsData;
                $i++;
            }

            if ((int)$simple_product->getWeightspec()) {
                $productsData = array( //['920'] = id of a simple product associated with this configurable
                    'label' => $simple_product->getAttributeText('weightspec'), //attribute label
                    'attribute_id' => (int)$weightspecAttributeId, //attribute ID of attribute 'color' in my store
                    'value_index' => (int)$simple_product->getWeightspec(), //value of 'Green' index of the attribute 'color'
                    'is_percent' => '0',
                    'pricing_value' => $simple_product->getPrice() //value for the pricing
                );
                $configurableProductsData[$simple_product->getId()] = $productsData;
                $configurableAttributesData[$i]['values'][] = $productsData;
                $i++;
            }

        }
    }
```

Please refer the tutorial for detailed explanation.
http://www.pearlbells.co.uk/set-associated-products-magento-1/